# Starting a daemon process but not proceeding until daemon startup process has finished in golang

Tags: go

I have two programs

1. Calls (2)
2. Starts a daemon process (a server) if it's not already started and then do some RPC against that server

I tried to start the daemon-process in (2) with `cmd.Run()`, but that left the `cmd.Run()` in (1) running forever, probably because of the daemon child process lingering.

```
cmd := exec.Command("daemonbinary")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()

// do other stuff and eventually exit the program would not work
```

I then figured I'd use `cmd.Start()` instead, but the problem is that I have to wait for the daemon process to actually start before I can continue.

How can that be achieved?

To recap, what I want to achieve is:

- start the daemon process in (2) if it's not already running and keep it running indefinitely
- only continue in (2) when that daemon process is properly started
- exit cleanly from (2) without any "relations" between the (2) process and the daemon process lingering.

**Edit:**

I tried starting it in a separate process group:

```
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Setpgid: true,
        Pgid:    0,
    }
```

this did not seem to work.

**Edit 2:**

I just remove two lines where I had attached `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr` and now the above seems to be working.

Would be nice however to have that `stdout` and `stderr` while the program is running?

Comment: Does `daemonbinary` have any status endpoint which you can pool until it says the deamon is ready? This way you can `cmd.Start()` and pool in a loop until the daemon is ready for rpc calls.

Comment: nope, but it prints "started", so it's def a possibility to capture it that way!

Comment: @salient: is it prints "started", is that not sufficient to know when the process is started? When stopping the process, what do you mean by exit cleanly without any "relations" between parent and child process? What are "relations"

Comment: yup, guess I have to figure out how to read "started" from that stream then :). I mean, it hangs indefinitely which leads me to believe that the (2) process and the daemon process are still related. And I even tried to start it in a separate process group.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you are describing sounds like something for an process control system/orchestrator like `docker-compose` or `supervisord`, which would allow you to run services in separate processes and check their state.

If you insist on staying within Go, I would suggest to read from daemon `StdoutPipe` periodically for new content until it's there and act upon it. But I find this solution quite hacky.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "sleep 2 && echo started && sleep 5")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    buffer := make([]byte, 7)
    for {
        stdout.Read(buffer)
        if string(buffer) == "started" {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    fmt.Println("Daemon started")

    yourRPCStuff()

    if err = cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to kill daemon: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you output to file and then read the file rather than just reading from `cmd.Stdout` directly?

Comment: @Adrian: cmd.Stdout implements `io.Writer`, so you cannot read from it. I tried using Cmd.StdoutPipe() to retrieve the stream I could read from, but I didn't succeed, maybe because the process didn't finish it didn't flush the output? I am not sure why, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: StdOutPipe should deliver unbuffered output, it is the preferred method for reading a command's stdout directly, using OS pipes. You could also do it yourself using `io.Pipe` which is a Go-implemented in-memory pipe. Using an intermediary file to read the output of a command you're forking out to seems like a horribly messy workaround to a simple problem. What if it's a long-running process with a lot of output? You're giving yourself a disk space constraint for absolutely no reason.

Comment: You are right, I messed up my tests by using buffer with len=0. Thanks for the comment, will update my answer.